# Android USB Functions?

Tags: android, usb

Are there any USB functions for Android devices (all user devices, not rooted)?

I'm curious because I might want to make an app that puts things through USB

Comment: Please define "Things", and the direction that these "things" will travel?

Answer (score 3):

Short answers are [no](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/e087205a7609443d) and [people are gagging for it](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=738), but depending on what you intend to do, the Android [bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) implementation is much simpler. (and you can treat Bluetooth as a basic serial connection if so inclined)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is rather an old question but I thought I'd add an answer representing current state given that it still shows up in searches.

Since API level 12 USB support has been added to the platform. It however a bit of a minefield as to whether a given device actually supports USB host mode and exactly what that means.

More details can be found on the [Google Android documentation pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes like Neil said you can try and use the Host API's. Otherwise you can use the Accessory Development Toolkit: http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html

Kevin