# USB programming in Android

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application which can access USB. But there is no API support for USB in Android. Can anyone suggest me, how can I do this?

I want to use my android phone as USB host.

Comment: What is USB supposed to mean here? Android has USB drivers. what kind of application you want to develop? please elaborate!

Comment: Read the links in the Related section of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695386/android-usb-functions looks relevant though I don't know if it's up to date.

Comment: by USB do you mean you want to access files from your OS to android or from android to OS for sync??  or anything else??

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do this except with your own hardware and your own firmware, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is no longer correct (it was correct at the time it was written) support for USB devices in two modes (accessory and host) was [added in API level 12](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html) which came to us later in 2011. In my experience the support and understanding is still a little patchy (though it may be my understanding that is the patchy part :-p )